# Shielding WiFi signal

Tags: antenna, wifi, coax

I have a device with WiFi connectivity. I want to shield this device from the outside, so no one can connect with the device, no matter how near he stands to it.

My device has a small antenna which connects to an SMA connector socket. Removing the antenna dampens the signal, but not well enough. Putting a metal cap on it with a 50 Ω impedance dampens it, but not enough. Is there any possible way that I can dampen the signal enough?

Comment: You can put it in a metal box

Comment: Wrap it in aluminum foil.  With the spare bits, you can make a nice hat ;~)

Comment: @VoltageSpike unfortunately its too big for it.

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen I am not paranoid, I have to comply with certain regulations (no matter how stupid they are) and the manufacturer won't sell a version without wifi connectivity.

Comment: There are faraday bags (plastic).  Some are see-through-ish.  Zip Lock style bags, that might keep the bad wifi's out.

Comment: "I have to comply with certain regulations"  Ya, I've been there...  I belly-ached enough about it that they finally just let it go (it was an unused Bluetooth interface in that case).  Good luck!

Comment: Remove the WiFi chip.  Or un-solder the pins that connect to the antenna.

Comment: Does the wifi ever need to work again? Cutting the antenna track(s) seems most likely to work.

Comment: @tomnexus that's not guaranteed to work. It could still receive and transmit with limited radiation - close range might still work. Wrapping it in tinfoil probably won't work because there will likely still be cables penetrating the box. Removing the WiFi chip is the best option, IMO.

Comment: @jason true, but it may fail to boot without the chip...I agree foil wrapping won't work, unless it's entirely battery powered, no wires, and a lot of foil.

Comment: This sounds like a TEMPEST, or related requirement.  If it is, and I walked into a room with an aluminum foil wrapped solution, I would be rapidly shown the door.

Comment: You could apply a strong 2.4 GHz signal directly to the antenna pin in a sort of on-board jamming. If the jamming signal is much stronger than any possibly received signal, it will overwhelm the WiFi receiver.